# Trouble with vue-cli: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env/data/built-ins.json'

Tags: vue.js, babeljs

Attempting to create a new vue project. I run:

```
yarn global add @vue/cli
vue create my-project
```

Then:

```
cd my-project
yarn serve
```

Right out of the gate I'm getting an error that I cannot resolve:

```
Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env/data/built-ins.json
```

In the auto-generated package.json (below) `@babel/preset-env` isn't listed as a dev dependency, but I assume it gets added automatically as a dependency of some of the vue stuff? Any idea what is going on?

Here are auto-generated files:

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

`babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Known issue, not something to solve on StackOverflow ~ https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3671

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that thread. Not being terribly experienced with yarn/babel, I assumed I was doing something wonky.

Comment: It's ok, I imagine there's going to be a lot of noise for this today :)

Comment: From the issue ~ _"This has been fixed in `@babel/preset-env@7.4.1`. You will need to delete `yarn.lock` / `package-lock.json` and run `yarn` / `npm i` again."_

Comment: That fixed my issue. So this issue was created and resolved in the last couple hours? Things move fast in the npm world...